# Getting values from an ajax call when using browser, but not in Postman

Tags: javascript, java, saml

I need to decode a string and tell if it is successful. I need to call `/dummy.do` first to encode the someString. Its output will be used by `/displayapp` to decode and find something in the decoded string, then returning the shortString and success values.

When I run this in browser, I am able to get response from the `/dummy.do` and `/displayapp` and render the . Response from the `/dummy.do` is "Long String", and response from `/displayapp` is "Short String" and "true". I'm even able to get the "hostname not prod" in the logs.

When I test `/dummy.do` in Postman, I'm able to get the "Long String". But when I tested `/displayapp` in Postman, I'm not able to output anything.
Both response status are 200, so I don't know why it's not displaying. If it is deployed in our server, there's an error 500 POST in the `/displayapp`

**SampleUI.tsx**

```
axios.post(contextPath + '/dummy.do', someString,
    {
        transformRequest: [
            (data, headers) => {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.set('someString', someString);
                return formData;
            }
        ]
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('response dummy', response)
        let longString = response.data.longString
        let hostname = window.location.hostname
        axios.post(contextPath + '/displayapp',
            { longString, hostname },
            {
                transformRequest: [
                    (data, headers) => {
                        const formData = new FormData();
                        formData.set('longString', longString);
                        formData.set('hostname', hostname);
                        return formData;
                    }
                ]
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('response displayapp', response)
                if (hostname == 'prodUrl.here') {
                    if (response.data.success == 'true') {
                        // some code here
                    }
                    else {
                        // some code here
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log('hostname not prod')
                    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
                }

            })
    })
```

**SampleController.java**

````
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dummy.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> dummy(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String someString) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // will do some encoding of someString and will assign it to longString
        // say value of longString is "Long String"

        resultMap.put("longString", longString);

        return resultMap;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/displayapp")
    public Map<String, Object> displayapp(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String longString, String hostname) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // will do some decoding of longString, find something from the string and will assign it to shortString
        // say value of shortString is "Short String"

        resultMap.put("shortString", shortString);
        resultMap.put("success", "true");

        return resultMap;
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: Could you post screenshots of your postman? That would help in figuring out what the problem is.